How to get every possible combination of values from two PHP arrays?
I have two arrays, people and fruit, each of which can have any number of elements from 1 to infinity.
Assuming that all of the fruit gets eaten, I need to output every possible combination of which people ate which fruit.
I have written this:
$people = array('Alice', 'Bob');
$fruit = array('apple', 'banana');

foreach ($people as $value1) {

    $combination = array();

    foreach ($fruit as $value2) {
        $combination[] = $value1.' ate the '.$value2;
    }

    echo '<p>'.json_encode($combination).'</p>';

}

It outputs this:
["Alice ate the apple","Alice ate the banana"]
["Bob ate the apple","Bob ate the banana"]

This output is incomplete, since it misses the mixed cases where Alice ate one fruit and Bob ate the other.
I think I need to code this as a recursive function, but I just can't get past the mental block of how that would work. I've been at this off and on for weeks.
My desired result:
["Alice ate the apple","Alice ate the banana"]
["Bob ate the apple","Bob ate the banana"]
["Alice ate the apple","Bob ate the banana"]
["Bob ate the apple","Alice ate the banana"]


@mickmackusa You're right, it seems like everyone is having a fruit feast! But no worries, he is just making sure no one leaves hungry.

The desired output would include every possible combination, like this:
["Alice ate the apple","Alice ate the banana"]
["Bob ate the apple","Bob ate the banana"]
["Alice ate the apple","Bob ate the banana"]
["Bob ate the apple","Alice ate the banana"]
